# How does drinking 25 mg-50mg Viagra every night cure Erectile Disfunction permanently?

Tags: medicine

https://www.webmd.com/erectile-dysfunction/news/20040513/nightly-viagra-may-restore-normal-erections#2

This article says that people taking viagra once daily can have erection restored permanently again.

Those who take viagra only when they're about to have sex do not.

I do not understand their reasoning why?

They said it helps make Endothelial cells better.

If that's the case, how come people that take viagra only when they're about to have sex do not improve?

Comment: Hmmm... I am basically asking if that research is true. Somehow you think I ask for my personal self.

Comment: I don’t see anything personal about this medical question...